# (not set) list name in Product List Performance in Google Analytics and its segment

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

Product List Performance report in Google Analytics has *(not set)* list. It happens when google can't find any action corresponding to any list prior to purchase. For example, visitor is landing to cart page or product page and immediately make purchase.

Q1: Does this attribution take place on session or user level?
[Help](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6014841?hl=en#product_attribution) is not clear.

In my case more than 30% of revenue corresponds to (not set). If attribution is on session scope the only reason left is session interruption after 30 minutes (default settings in GA). It's possible that in first session visitor adds items to cart and in the second session buy it. So I change session timeout to 4 hours (maximum allowed). Will wait for result, but doubt big positive effect.

While waiting I decide to make custom segment of session where List Name was (not set) and purchase was made. And I was greatly surprised that all revenue of the day was reported, while in GA Product List Performance report there's only :) one third. Obviously I made mistake in segment definition.

My segment:

```
metrics=ga:itemRevenue
segment=sessions::condition::ga:productListName==(not set);ga:itemRevenue>0
```

I've tried another way like sequence, but failed.

```
segment=sessions::sequence::ga:productListName==(not set);ga:itemQuantity>0
```

Q2: How can I make segment with sessions with purchases corresponding to (not set) list?